# How to pass a ReactJS function as a callback to a external JS function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am implementing a credit card payment form in ReactJS using a 3rd party bank JS which works using iframes.

The logic is I load bank's javascript in my page, something like this:

```
<script src="https://my-bank.com/super-secure-script.js"></script>
```

Then I collect user's CC data in my ReactJS component, then call a function like this:

```
window.Bank.SendPayment(CC, this.paymentCompletedCallback);

 ...

paymentCompletedCallback = (result) => {
  // process payment result here, inside my component
}
```

The problem is: the code inside `super-secure-script.js` cannot find the callback `this.paymentCompletedCallback`, because it is inside inside my component.

The question is: how can I pass to an external script a reference to a react object function?

Comment: I suppose Sendpayment is async ? Maybe this.paymentCompletedCallback.bind(this) solves the problem.

Comment: @Lumpenstein, using an arrow function automatically binds this in scope

Comment: Have you tried just using `paymentCompletedCallback` without a reference to this?

Comment: @Claeusdev automatic `this` binding for fat arrow is a misconception (I believe), it dont have its own `this` thus bubbles up to use parent's `this` which in case of `async` gets lost and undefined most likely.

Comment: @Claeusdev you are 100% correct, missed that part ;)

Comment: @Rikin yeah thats right.

Comment: @Lumpenstein: yes, `Sendpayment` is async, of course...

Comment: if `Sendpayment` is async then i guess you could try and `await` paymentCompletedCallback

Comment: @MarcoS I tried creating tiny example of async and it seems working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-external-js-callback-return?file=index.js

Comment: Thanks, everybody! I suppose the `bind` did the trick! I did never really understood that `bind` thing, sorry for wasting your time!  
If @Lumpenstein want to post his first comment a an answer, I will accept it...  
Many thanks to @Rikin, too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this.paymentCompletedCallback.**bind(this)** may solve the problem.

Here is another example of when binding is necessary, hope that makes it more clear to you:

```
var Button = function(content) { 
  this.content = content;
};
Button.prototype.click = function() {
  console.log(this.content + ' clicked');
};

var myButton = new Button('OK');
myButton.click();

var looseClick = myButton.click;
looseClick(); // not bound, 'this' is not myButton - it is the global object

var boundClick = myButton.click.bind(myButton);
boundClick(); // bound, 'this' is myButton
```

Answer (score 2):

You can attach the function to the `window` object:

```
const Component = () => {

  const func = () => {
    console.log('do something');
  };

  window.func = func;
};
```

Comment: I think this simple solution should work, too... Didn't thing about it... :-(
But the `bind` looks more like a `react`-thing... :-)

Comment: Bind is a JavaScript prototype. In the React Component world, if you organize your components into classes and need to change the state prop from a callback, you just bind your function to `this`.

`funA() {
   window._reactLoadingCB = this.ready.bind(this);
}

ready() {
   const { result } = this.state;
   console.log('if you have result set, this will work', result);
}`